# about Code merge and SVN (4 developers 1 mutual server) ---Source code management issue non technical

Tags: java, svn, merge-conflict-resolution

I am now working in a team of 4 (Dev team). We all develop features and fix defects on our local environment. We are using SVN for code management.

A common issue is that:
Developer A's source code works on his local machine (Version 1.5)
Developer B's source code works on his local machine (Version 1.2)
(different version may have some difference on DB structure and source code etc)

When developer A commits his code to SVN (like 0002)
SVN source code will automatically be deployed to Testing Server for a senior QA for verify

After that, Developer B commits his code to SVN (0003)
The source code does not work due to the conflict/environment issue for 0002

In this case, I want to ask. How to merge the code and make sure it run (we don't have master version for a period of time)? Any methodologies?

Comment: Take updates first to avoid conflicts then resolve issues if any then check-in your code in SVN.

Comment: Pull down latest updates to your local machine before pushing. Fix and merge any conflicts locally. Then push the merged result to source control.

Comment: The problem was my project ,always changing database structure, if I can just simply get the latest update, it will throw a lot of errors. Does ecplise-SVN manage sql script also ???

Comment: Ask you Developer B to update his working copy . You should always update your working copy regularly . Make it a habit . This will help to solve source code conflicts .

Comment: Coming to your second issue , Subversion is just a versioning tool it does not know weather a file is sql or .java . SVN will version them anyway . So updating working copy will make sure Developer B gets the latest code and sql scripts .

Comment: regarding your question "How to merge the code and make sure it run " . Can you be a little more specific ?